# How to clone and remove divs in one click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, load, bind

I already checked everywhere to find a clear answer but i couldn't find. I just need an advice to how i'm gonna do.

What i want to do is :

**to clone this block with all EVENTS(VERY IMPORTANT)**

```
    <div class="backgrounds remove-handle">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="bg1" href="#"><img src="assets/backgrounds/small/01.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a class="bg2" href="#"><img src="assets/backgrounds/small/02.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="bg3"><img src="assets/backgrounds/small/03.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="bg4"><img src="assets/backgrounds/small/04.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="bg5"><img src="assets/backgrounds/small/05.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="bg6"><img src="assets/backgrounds/small/06.jpg"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

$('.backgrounds').clone().appendTo("#droppable");

and remove the original one. I just need cloned div blocks. And users can make it anytime. This process doesn't has to trigger itself for one time.

Thanks so much!

Comment: jQuery's `clone` allows for the copying of events.

Comment: @Mouser what if want to remove old cloned content and new content with fadeIn?